# In odoo10 how to enable pager in a dasboard whenever we click on a record?

Tags: javascript, odoo, odoo-10, dashboard

I have added a model having three records to my dashboard.But when i click on any record, it only shows that single record and pager is disabled. I am attaching the images. Can anybody help?

This is one of the three records that I click on
[image: A screenshot of a dashboard]

These are the three records that I have added. When I click on one, the pager is disabled and it only shows one.

[image]

Comment: Inlined the images so answerers don't have to navigate away from StackOverflow

Comment: @JamesCoyle Watch out on your edit because it displayed the same image twice instead of using each image originally posted

Comment: So, how can i show multiple records with pager enabled when ever i click any record on my tree view in a dashboard.

Comment: @travisw My apologies. Not sure how I managed that...